# WPF MVVM binding - list is not refreshing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I'm getting a list from the database. I have a button that adds a new user and then the list should refresh. However, this does not happen. Somebody help me?

**Model:**

```
namespace ManagementProjectSystem.Model
{
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public int UserRoleID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreateAccount { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<UserContact> UserContacts { get; set; }
        public virtual UserRole UserRole { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
using ManagementProjectSystem.DAL;
using ManagementProjectSystem.Model;
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ManagementProjectSystem.ViewModel
{
    class AdminViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private readonly ManagementProjectSystemContext dbContext = new ManagementProjectSystemContext();

        private List<User> _Users { get; set; }
        private string _UserRole { get; set; }
        private string _Name { get; set; }
        private string _Surname { get; set; }
        private string _Login { get; set; }
        private string _Password { get; set; }

        [Obsolete]
        public List<User> Users
        {
            get
            {
                return _Users = dbContext.User.ToList();
            }
            set
            {
                _Users = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => Users);
            }
        }

        public List<UserRole> UsersRole
        {
            get
            {
                return dbContext.UserRole.ToList();
            }
        }

        public string UserRole
        {
            get
            {
                return _UserRole;
            }
            set
            {
                _UserRole = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(UserRole); //OnPropertyChanged(() => UserRole);
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _Name;
            }
            set
            {
                _Name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(Name); //OnPropertyChanged(() => UserRole);
            }
        }

        public string Surname
        {
            get
            {
                return _Surname;
            }
            set
            {
                _Surname = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(Surname); //OnPropertyChanged(() => UserRole);
            }
        }

        public string Login
        {
            get
            {
                return _Login;
            }
            set
            {
                _Login = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(Login); //OnPropertyChanged(() => UserRole);
            }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get
            {
                return _Password;
            }
            set
            {
                _Password = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(Password); //OnPropertyChanged(() => UserRole);
            }
        }

        public ICommand AddUserButton { get; set; }

        public AdminViewModel()
        {
            AddUserButton = new DelegateCommand(AddUser);
        }

        private void AddUser()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(_UserRole + " " + _Name + " " + _Surname + " " + _Login + " " + _Password);
            var userRole = dbContext.UserRole.Where(n => n.Nazwa.ToString().Equals(_UserRole)).SingleOrDefault();
            int userRoleID = userRole.UserRoleID;

            User user = new User() {Name = _Name, Surname = _Surname, Login = _Login, Password = _Password, DateCreateAccount = DateTime.Now, UserRoleID = userRoleID };

            dbContext.User.Add(user);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            //_Users = dbContext.User.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**View - XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="ManagementProjectSystem.Admin"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ManagementProjectSystem"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Admin" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ListViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Users">
                <Grid Background="RosyBrown">

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="396*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="396*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                                <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}" Header="Surname"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Surname}" />
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>

                    <Grid Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label>Name:</Label>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" Text="{Binding Path = Name}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1">Surname</Label>
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" Text="{Binding Path = Surname}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="2">Login:</Label>
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" Text="{Binding Path = Login}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="3">Password:</Label>
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" Text="{Binding Path = Password}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="4">User role:</Label>
                        <ComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Path = UsersRole}" DisplayMemberPath="Nazwa"
                                  SelectedValuePath="Nazwa" SelectedValue="{Binding UserRole}">

                        </ComboBox>

                        <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding AddUserButton}">Add user</Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>

            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**View - XAML.cs**

```
namespace ManagementProjectSystem
{
    public partial class Admin : Window
    {
        public Admin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AdminViewModel vm = new AdminViewModel();
            this.DataContext = vm;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just starting to learn WPF and learn the MVVM pattern. I apologize for my English if there is something wrong written.
I use Prism and Entity Framework. What can I improve in the code to make the list refresh work after adding a new user? And generally the code is good?

Comment: It won't work because this is not observable: `dbContext.User`. And this `Users` will raise an event if you reset the property altogether not simply adding something to `dbContext.User`.

Comment: Use ObservableCollection instead of list.

Comment: @KevinCook how do get users then? dbContext.User.ToList(); gives error.

Comment: @CodingYoshi when I write in code: Users = dbContext.User.ToList(); in function AddUser then it work. But I don't know if this is a good solution. And now this function is [Obsolete].

Comment: I know it works that way and I said that in my previous comment. When you set the `Users` property, the property raises an even and notifies all clients to rebind. Ask the person who marked it obsolete and find out what their plan is. Most likely they marked it obsolete because they could foresee the issue you're running into and many other issues. I suggest you use ObservableCollection or speak with the person who marked it obsolete so your plans are in accordance with eachother.

Comment: `MessageBox` in a ViewModel is also code smell and goes against MVVM.

Comment: @CodingYoshi When I use ObservableCollection I don't know how to get data from the database and I have errors. I used MessageBox just for the test to check if anything works as I started writing it. When everything is fine, it will be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ObservableCollection` if you are going to add (or remove) individual items from it and want the View to update when that happens. It's not mandatory to use `ObservableCollection`, but if you don't, then the UI will need to reload the entire collection when items are added (or removed). It's up to you to decide whether that's a performance concern.

Currently, you are reloading the collection from the data store on every access of the Users property. This is not good.

**Option 1 - Keep using `List<User>`:**

I suggest first changing the `Users` property to avoid loading from the data store on every Get:

```
public List<User> Users
{
    get
    {
        if (_Users == null)
        {
            _Users = dbContext.User.ToList();
        }
        return _Users;
    }
    set
    {
        _Users = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(() => Users);
    }
}
```

Then in the `AddUser` method, add the new `User` to the list and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `Users` property:

```
...
dbContext.User.Add(user);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
_Users.Add(user);
OnPropertyChanged(() => Users);
```

---

**Option 2 - Use `ObservableCollection<User>`:**

If you do want to use `ObservableCollection` as suggested in comments, make the following changes:

This line:

```
private List<User> _Users { get; set; }
```

Becomes:

```
private ObservableCollection<User> _Users { get; set; }
```

The `Users` property becomes:

```
public List<User> Users
{
    get
    {
        if (_Users == null)
        {
            _Users = new ObservableCollection<User>(dbContext.User);
        }
        return _Users;
    }
    set
    {
        _Users = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(() => Users);
    }
}
```

And **remove** the `OnPropertyChanged(() => Users);` from the `AddUser` method (because the `ObservableCollection` will fire its own `CollectionChanged` event instead when you add to the collection, which will update the View).

Note: in the above, I am assuming `dbContext.User` implements `IEnumerable<User>` so a `ToList()` is unnecessary if passing it to the `ObservableCollection` constructor (this avoids creating a useless list during that step).

Comment: Option 1: Did not work. It must stay as it was: Users = dbContext.User.ToList();. I've tried it like you. When I added: OnPropertyChanged(() => Users); it not work. And such information, OnPropertyChanged visual studio treats as obsolete and information appears to use RaisePropertyChanged.

Comment: Option 2: dbContext.User it looks like this: public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }. public List<User> Users I change to  public ObservableCollection<User> Users. It worked :) I wonder if: _Users.Add(user); is necessary in option 2?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Prism but I see OnPropertyChanged and RaisePropertyChanged in your code already, so use whichever is appropriate for Prism to get the ViewModel to raise it's PropertyChanged event so that the View can update itself when the Users property changes. In the second case, _Users.Add is necessary because the View is bound to _Users (the ObservableCollection) and only sees items added therein. Either way, glad it worked for you.